# What is domainFn and measureFn in graphs from charts_flutter package?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I tried to look at library docs and tried to find it online but almost every source has skipped the explanation of these functions. I can still get my app to behave the way I want it but I would like get clarity on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In math, a function has a domain and range (or measure, in chart speak). Loosely speaking, The domain are the input values, and the range (measure) are the output values. For charts, commonly the `domain` is the `x` axis, and the `range` (measure) is the `y` axis.

So if you're making a line chart of the squares of all integers from 0 to 100, then `domainFn` would simply be `(i) => i` while the `measureFn` would be `(i) => i * i`